# Modifying Text files with awk or sed or both (again)

Tags: unix, text, sed, awk

I'm really sorry, I'm having problems with the same old thing - awk and sed

I want to convert large text files containing:

```
>hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_12513 range=chr1:52035541-52035716 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
CACACATACTTTTATTCAAGCCTCAGAGCAACCCTGCAAAATGAGTATTA
TCTCCACTTTACAATCAGGAGGCTGAGTCATAAGGAGGTGAGTCACCTGC
CTAGGGCCACATAGCTAGCAAGGAGCCAAGCTGGAATTTTAAGCCACGTT
TGTCTGATTCTTTCTGCATACCATGC
>hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_13212 range=chr1:186122154-186122314 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
ATCTTCAGGGACAAGTTTTTACAAACTCTCTTAATGGTTTTACCACCCTC
CCTATCAGGACCAAGATCAAATACTTGATGTAAGGCATTTGTTTAATTTT
CTTTAGACAAAGAGGATAGTAATTCTTGCATAAACGTTTTTGTGTATCAT
CCATAAAATAT
```

etc, etc

To:

```
>range=chr1:52035541-52035716 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
CACACATACTTTTATTCAAGCCTCAGAGCAACCCTGCAAAATGAGTATTA
TCTCCACTTTACAATCAGGAGGCTGAGTCATAAGGAGGTGAGTCACCTGC
CTAGGGCCACATAGCTAGCAAGGAGCCAAGCTGGAATTTTAAGCCACGTT
TGTCTGATTCTTTCTGCATACCATGC
>range=chr1:186122154-186122314 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
ATCTTCAGGGACAAGTTTTTACAAACTCTCTTAATGGTTTTACCACCCTC
CCTATCAGGACCAAGATCAAATACTTGATGTAAGGCATTTGTTTAATTTT
CTTTAGACAAAGAGGATAGTAATTCTTGCATAAACGTTTTTGTGTATCAT
CCATAAAATAT
```

I've tried `awk 'NR==1{sub(/^[^ ]* /,"")} 1'` and `sed -i '1s/\w\+ //'` but nothing is working.

Comment: So, are these multi-line records?  I thought they were just wrapped for presentation.  If so, what is the beginning of a record, something similar to **hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_13212**?  And is the final result just a long string, without those UserTrack fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to remove the first word in the lines that begin with a greater-than sign. In that case  you can use `awk` like this:

```
awk '{sub(/^>[^ ]* /,">")} 1'
```

Remove the restriction, `NR==1` means that the following block will only be executed on the first line. Also include `>` in the pattern and replacement.

Output:

```
>range=chr1:52035541-52035716 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
CACACATACTTTTATTCAAGCCTCAGAGCAACCCTGCAAAATGAGTATTA
TCTCCACTTTACAATCAGGAGGCTGAGTCATAAGGAGGTGAGTCACCTGC
CTAGGGCCACATAGCTAGCAAGGAGCCAAGCTGGAATTTTAAGCCACGTT
TGTCTGATTCTTTCTGCATACCATGC
>range=chr1:186122154-186122314 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
ATCTTCAGGGACAAGTTTTTACAAACTCTCTTAATGGTTTTACCACCCTC
CCTATCAGGACCAAGATCAAATACTTGATGTAAGGCATTTGTTTAATTTT
CTTTAGACAAAGAGGATAGTAATTCTTGCATAAACGTTTTTGTGTATCAT
CCATAAAATAT
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `sed`:

```
sed '/^>/s/[^ ]* />/' file
```

Results:

```
>range=chr1:52035541-52035716 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
CACACATACTTTTATTCAAGCCTCAGAGCAACCCTGCAAAATGAGTATTA
TCTCCACTTTACAATCAGGAGGCTGAGTCATAAGGAGGTGAGTCACCTGC
CTAGGGCCACATAGCTAGCAAGGAGCCAAGCTGGAATTTTAAGCCACGTT
TGTCTGATTCTTTCTGCATACCATGC
>range=chr1:186122154-186122314 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
ATCTTCAGGGACAAGTTTTTACAAACTCTCTTAATGGTTTTACCACCCTC
CCTATCAGGACCAAGATCAAATACTTGATGTAAGGCATTTGTTTAATTTT
CTTTAGACAAAGAGGATAGTAATTCTTGCATAAACGTTTTTGTGTATCAT
CCATAAAATAT
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you only want to remove the first field, up to the first space.  You can do this:

```
cut -f2- -d ' '
```

Comment: not really, check the line 1861223... and last line ... I don't know what is the rule... :)